# Validate input from an inputbox without leaving the inputbox

Tags: regex, validation, vim, input

I created a function with an inputdialog to move lines conditionally (tnx to Romainl).
First thing to do is a search, then to invoke the code below.

My Code:

```
   if !exists("char")
     let char = "Move Lines with search match after/before? 
        \ \n
        \ \nMove Line Backwards: Start input with: '?' 
        \ \nMove Line Forwards: Start input with: '/' 
        \ \n
        \ \np.e.
        \ \n?=\\s*$           
        \"
   endif  
   let a = inputdialog(char)
   if a == ""
     return
   endif

   if matchstr(a, '^?') != ''
     let minplus = '-'
   elseif matchstr(a, '^/') != ''
     let minplus = '+'
   else
     echo "wrong input: input does not start with '?' or '/'"
     return
   endif
```

I would like to change the "return" command in a "return back to inputdialog" command:
I would like to check the input entered in the inputbox immediately without leaving the inputbox, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `inputdialog()` is a single, blocking call in Vimscript. None of your code can run while it's open. No events (that can be hooked into with `:autocmd` are fired. In general, there's no parallelism in Vim.

The best you can do is re-launch the `inputdialog()` (possibly initialized with the previously entered text) when the validation fails.

Alternatively, you'd have to implement your own input control (e.g. using `getchar()`). There, you can run validation while waiting for the next pressed character.

Comment: If I changes `return` in `let a = inputdialog(char)` the input is not controlled. How can I go back to the first `let a = inputdialog(char)` in my code above? Vim doesn't have Sub routines, isn't it?

Comment: Vim doesn't have _goto_ (fortunately), but you can put a `:while 1` ... `:endwhile` around the input + validation, and only `:return` out of it when the validation passes.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the solution (using `break` in stead of `return`). Only thing what still doesn't work is that when I press the `Cancel` button or `<ESC>` key in the inputdialog it doesn't go out of the loop.

Comment: That case returns the empty string; if you check for that and `:break`, it should leave the loop, too.